# Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set on h = ie.hwnd line

Tags: excel, vba

I am running the following code below, but I am getting the Run-time error 91 on the h = ie.hwnd line. However,when I define this variable in another module, I do not get this error. How should I fix this error?

```
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long

'Public Const CB_FINDSTRING = &H14C
Public Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Sub ClickSave() '(ClaimNumber As String)
Sleep 1000

Dim o As IUIAutomation
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim Completed As Object

Do
    Dim h As Long
    h = ie.hwnd 'Error on this line :(
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)

    If h <> 0 Then
        Dim count As Long
        count = 0
        Exit Do
    Else
        Sleep 100
        count = count + 1
        If count = 50 Then Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of `ie` so `set ie = new InternetExplorer` along those lines

Comment: You can use something like this: `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but they both give me the Compile error: Invalid use of property error. :(

Comment: Always helps to include in your question a description of what your code is supposed to do, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Oh never mind. Those suggestions do work. I forgot to put "set". Thank you very much for your help! XD